# バニラJSで2次元配列をmap,reduceで変換するには

Tags: javascript

```
// 2次元配列
var arr =[
  [1,2,3],
  [2,3,4],
  [5,6,7]
]
```

を↓のように2次元配列の各配列要素の合計を出したいのですが

```
[
  [6],
  [9],
  [18]
]
```

---

```
var arr1 = arr.map(function(val){
  val.reduce(function(a,b){return a+b})
})
```

で求める答えと合致するとおもったのですが、
結果は `[null,null,null]` です。
わかる方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご回答お願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

mapの中の関数にreturnを加えれば、正しく動くと思います。

```
var arr1 = arr.map(function(val){
    return val.reduce(function(a,b){return a+b})
})
```

Answer (score -1):

うまくいきました。

```
arr.map(function(val){
  return val.reduce(function(a,b){return a+b;})
})
```

ならうまくできました。

```
arr.map(function(val){ return
   val.reduce(function(a,b){return a+b;})
})
```

`return` が上にあるとうまくいきませんでした。
ありがとうございます

Comment: `return` の後に改行を入れると動かないのは、文が終ったと見なされ、セミコロン ( `;` )が補完されているからだと思います。どうしても改行を入れたい時は `return` で返す値を `( )` で囲み、改行は `(` の後に入れれば大丈夫です。